# Sharing Asset Image from Android custom IME, working for everything except Gmail and MMS

Tags: android, android-intent, ime

Ok this might be long post as I have spent the last 3 days (18 hrs) on this.  I created a custom keyboard ext for iOS and was tasked to do the same for Android.  I have everything working like I want giving the user keyboards to use that are interchangeable between letters and numbers/symbols.  As well as a recycler view for custom emoji categories across the top of the keyboard.  On selection of one of the categories (according to which was selected) a horizontal recycler view of the images is displayed.  On selection of one of these images it should send the image to where the user wants.

This works for Facebook, Twitter, Hipchat, Google drive and keep, FB Messagener, however with mms and gmail I am given the error, unable to attach photo.

I have a custom content provider class using a ParcelFileDescriptor with a data pipe,

```
public class ***ContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = null;

    try {
        pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
        AssetManager assests = getContext().getResources().getAssets();
        new TransferThread(assests.open(uri.getLastPathSegment()), new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(pipe[1])).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pipe[0];
}
```

There was a thread on here that stated that the MMS looks for a Cursor with the columns "Images.Media.DATA" and "Images.Media.MIME_TYPE" before calling the openFile of the content provider.  I do not have a SQLite db created so I create a matrixCursor and return it here...I looked at the API for the media columns [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html) and changed my cursor to match(along with values for the row to match but didn't include in this post):

```
@Override
public Cursor query( Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal )
{
    String[] columns = new String[] {"DATA", "DATE_ADDED", "DATE_MODIFIED", "DISPLAY_NAME", "HEIGHT",
            "MIME_TYPE", "SIZE", "TITLE", "WIDTH"};        
    MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);

    matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[] {uri.getLastPathSegment(), "image/png"});

//        return matrixCursor;

    // TODO: Implement this method
    return super.query( uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder, cancellationSignal );
}
```

except it causes the MMS application to force close.

My sharing intent code is here:

```
@Override
public void emojiSelection(String emojiID) {
    Uri theUri = Uri.parse("content://com.***.***.***/"+emojiID);

    //Sharing intent code
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/png");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    //Add data to intent
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, theUri);
    Intent intent2 = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using...");
    intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
```

I have the provider tags in my manifest, with read permissions and exported set to true

Stack Trace for the MMS application crash:

```
09-14 15:23:31.517 30287-30580/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: addAttachment
                                               Process: com.android.mms, PID: 30287
                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                   at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:451)
                                                   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                   at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
                                                   at com.android.mms.util.bz.b(FileInfoUtils.java:275)
                                                   at com.android.mms.ui.to.a(MessageUtils.java:15213)
                                                   at com.android.mms.composer.mt.a(ComposerAttachController.java:128)
                                                   at com.android.mms.composer.SimpleEditorBottomPanel.a(SimpleEditorBottomPanel.java:76)
                                                   at com.android.mms.composer.dk.a(BottomPanel.java:307)
                                                   at com.android.mms.composer.dk.a(BottomPanel.java:296)
                                                   at com.android.mms.util.da.run(HandleComposerAttachment.java:3316)
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: "except it causes the MMS application to force close" -- examine the Java stack trace from that app and see if it gives you any clues. Also, FWIW, [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) offers serving assets out of the box, in case you want to try it and see if you have better luck, or if it gives you any clues as to where your implementation is going awry.

Comment: hheeey CommonsWare....yea your streamprovider is great btw...I did look at the stack...well i'll just update my question with the trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `MatrixCursor` is malformed. You claim to be supporting nine columns. Your only row has two columns, saying that `DATE` is the last path segment and `DATE_ADDED`. If your `MatrixCursor` will only support two columns, only supply those two columns in the constructor, and make sure that they have the column names that you want.

Second, you're supposed to support [the `OpenableColumns`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/OpenableColumns.html#DISPLAY_NAME). You are not returning the size.

Third, your column names are wrong. Where possible, refer to constants in the SDK. For example, there is no `DISPLAY_NAME` column. There *is* a column identified by `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`, but the actual string is `_display_name`.

Finally, you throw away the `MatrixCursor`, after having gone to the trouble of creating it. Uncomment your `return` statement that returns the `MatrixCursor`, and remove the `super.query()` statement.

Those should help with compatibility.

Comment: Sorry I took that code straight from Android Studio, I had the matrix uncommented at the time because it was crashing the mms application, and I know that this is only showing a row with two values(I did fill in the constructor, but did not want to share the information provided).  I was following the Media columns constants from the SDK, but I see what you are saying now that I look at it after a break, i'm not actually using the constant values.  Thank you for all your help and suggesting the OpenableColumns, I will try that for sure.

Comment: I wanted to give an update in case someone comes across this with the same issue.  I changed the columns values to be equal to the actual constant values and it worked like a charm using the Media Columns.  I will say that you can't use a wildcard character when setting the MimeType in the Cursor(I tried 'image/*' at first and it gave me a unsupported file type, so I changed it to 'image/png' and everything was great).  Thanks so much for your help CommonsWare, I don't know why I didn't use the constant values to begin with, I blame it on tired eyes lol.